# Update value and keep the key on python dictionary

Tags: python, django, dictionary

I have a parking place app where I want to calculate the available days in a week, and the total available hours per day.

I have different cities with different timeshifts, some have full time (for example 7:00-20:00) and others have separated time (for example 7:00-14:00 and 16:00-20:00).

Here is the loop I tried:

```
def get_available_hours(self):
    _dict = []
    time = 0
    query_set = TimeTableCity.objects.filter(city_id=self._city_id)
    for i in query_set:
        initial_hour_datetime = datetime.strptime(i.initial_hour, '%H:%M')
        end_hour_datetime = datetime.strptime(i.end_hour, '%H:%M')
        time = end_hour_datetime - initial_hour_datetime
        _dict.append({i.day_table.id: time.seconds / 3600})
        time = 0
    return _dict
```

And the returned dict at the end is the following:

```
[{4: 5.0}, {4: 4.0}, {5: 5.0}, {5: 4.0}, {1: 5.0}, {1: 4.0}, {2: 5.0}, {2: 4.0}, {3: 5.0}, {3: 4.0}]
```

The key is the day of the week, and the value is the hours for that shift.
Is there a way to sum the values for the same key?

Comment: Please share your model(s): `TimeTableCity` and related models.

Comment: Is it completely necessary? It is working as intended, I just want to sum the values with the same key @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: @peplover It looks like you use a `CharField` instead of a `TimeField` to store the times? Plus the calculation you perform can be done on the database side quite easily. As Willem Van Onsem states you should add your model, since then people can suggest better solutions.

Comment: @peplover: it is better to do these aggregates at the *database* level, since that is faster, and requires less bandwidth.

Comment: Since I can't modify the database, I just had to do the way I as showed. Sorry if i didn't specified that

Comment: @peplover: but we do not *change* the database at all, it is simply making a query that does the work for us at the database level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `get` function.

```py
def get_available_hours(self):
    _dict = {}
    time = 0
    query_set = TimeTableCity.objects.filter(city_id=self._city_id)
    for i in query_set:
        initial_hour_datetime = datetime.strptime(i.initial_hour, '%H:%M')
        end_hour_datetime = datetime.strptime(i.end_hour, '%H:%M')
        time = end_hour_datetime - initial_hour_datetime

        _dict[i.day_table.id] = _dict.get(i.day_table.id, 0) + (time.seconds / 3600)
        
        time = 0
    return _dict
```

Comment: or use [`defaultdict`](https://realpython.com/python-defaultdict/)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Counter. https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter
It can be used to sum values of seperate dicts with the same key.
IE

```
from collections import Counter

a = {'a': 5, 'b': 7}
b = {'a': 3, 'b': 2, 'c': 5}
dict(Counter(a)+Counter(b))
```

--

```
Out[7]: {'a': 8, 'b': 9, 'c': 5}
```

Answer (score 0):

This method works without needing to import, someone will probably comment a cleaner method though, but I think it is pretty readable

```
d = [{4: 5.0}, {4: 4.0}, {5: 5.0}, {5: 4.0}, {1: 5.0}, {1: 4.0}, {2: 5.0}, {2: 4.0}, {3: 5.0}, {3: 4.0}]
summed = {}
for item in d:
    day_of_week = list(item.keys())[0]
    if day_of_week not in summed:
        summed[day_of_week] = item[day_of_week]
    else:
        summed[day_of_week] += item[day_of_week]
```

result:

```
Out[12]: {4: 9.0, 5: 9.0, 1: 9.0, 2: 9.0, 3: 9.0}
```

Comment: @peplover no worries :)